# Can't pass String via Extra on an Android grid view

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, extras

I have a gridView and I want to pass an Extra via an intent. 
It usually works, but not here:

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, 
                                              int position, long id) {
                        String prompt = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BookletsGridActivity.this, PdfReader.class);
                        intent.putExtra("pdfurl", prompt);
                        System.out.println("prompt --->" + prompt);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                         startActivity(intent);
                      }
                    });
```

I have no idea why it is not working: I check prompt value and it's the right one.

Comment: what is the problem, is there an error?

Comment: Have you retrieve your String in Your Second Activity? Post Code for that.

Comment: I have no error, but I don't retrieve the right extra on my destination activity.

Comment: I've got null for the get extras

Comment: how and where are you retrieving the extra? can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I close this one. Thanks for help. I did some mistakes with the data I wanted to send. Extras are not guilty! ^^

Comment: hey I am getting the exact error in my gridview, just passing the path of the image and its printing null at the other activity.....any idea what went wrong with your code?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I don't think extras was the issue. I cleaned my code and it was ok. Paste some code to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

use following one
    **BookletsGridActivity.class**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(BookletsGridActivity.this, PdfReader.class);
    intent.putExtra("pdfurl", prompt);
    System.out.println("prompt --->" + prompt);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**PdfReader.class**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
String value = intent.getStringExtra("pdfurl", "");
```